# AJAX Display words in span using jquery split

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display words in a span by getting input from textbox. When the user clicks the button it will display the word in span. It only works if one word is used. So what I'm trying to do is, I want to make the adding of words more efficient, so I will add words that is separated by comma eg,. word, word1, word2. I tried using jquery split to explode the string. But the word is displaying as undefined. Anyway the codes I posted works only on single word, I'm trying to achieve the method using jquery split to add words which is separated by comma. Any idea on this?

```
$(document).on('click', '#wordlistsave', function() 
{

    var user = /* some values */
    var title = /* some values */
    var words = (this, is, just, sample, data) /* assume this is the value */
    var postID =/* some values; */

    var testBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                        .attr("id", words);

    var dataString = 'user='+user+'&title='+title+'&words='+words+'&id='+postID;

    <?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
        if(words)
        {
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?=plugins_url('wordlistsave.php', __FILE__ )?>",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(postID)
                {                      
                    testBoxDiv.html('<span> '+words+' </span>);                     
                }
            });
        }

    <?php else: ?>
        alert('Please login.');
    <?php endif; ?>
});
```

**EDIT UPDATE:**
This is what I have come up with. I used jquery split to turn the string into an array which has a delimiter comma. and then I used for loop to display the words. But I'm getting "undefined" output. But when I refresh, the words displayed properly. Any idea on this?

```
 var words = word.split(", ");


                    var testBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                                        .attr("id", words);


                    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                    {                   
                        var dataString = 'user='+user+'&title='+title+'&words='+words[i]+'&id='+postID;

                            <?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
                                    if(words[i])
                                    {

                                        $.ajax({ 
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "<?=plugins_url('wordlistsave.php', __FILE__ )?>",
                                            data: dataString,
                                            cache: false,
                                            success: function(postID)
                                            {

                                                testBoxDiv.css({"margin-bottom":"5px"});
                                                testBoxDiv.after().html('<span id="'+words[i]+'" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="./wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/pdfpreview/delete_icon.png" title="Delete word"></span>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="words[]" value="'+ words[i]+ '">'+words[i] );
                                                testBoxDiv.appendTo("#test_container"); 



                                            }
                                        });
                                    }


                            <?php else: ?>
                                    alert('Please login.');
                            <?php endif; ?>



                    }
```

Comment: what is the data returned by your `$.ajax` call? `(this, is, just, sample, data)` is a string not an array of words, so im assuming you're doing something to the words in your `php` file?

Comment: Yes it is not an array yet, but if you used words.split(", "), it will become array right? Correct me if I'm wrong. This is where the confusing part goes.

Comment: I would kill the `()` braces (unless your PHP needs them), as they will mess up a `.split()` call by leaving the first word as `"(this"`. you will need to tell it that the data is a list of strings not variables but adding quotes around them `"this, is, just, sample, data"`. Personally, i would start with them already split. JS uses square brackets for list notation, . ie. `["this", "is", "just", "sample", "data"]` and instead use `.join(',')` to pass it as a string to your PHP.

Comment: It is just a string, it will be converted to array when split function is used.

Comment: `var words = (this, is, just, sample, data);` is not a valid string. you need to use something like `var words = "this, is, just, sample, data"` to have words be a string. I also notice you're performing an ajax call for _each_ word, i feel there must be a better way to do this, by handling multiple words on your `php` side

Comment: Thank you for siting my mistake. Basically the words displays properly when refresh. Only not working when the button is click. So probably the mistake here is in the ajax success.

Comment: `var testBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", words);` you are assigning the entire words string as the `id` to `testBoxDiv`. try moving this variable into your ajax success and change it to: `var testBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", words[i]);`

Comment: the word is undefined, but when I refresh, it is there. It works fine after refreshing

Comment: sounds like possibly a caching issue then, try clearing your cache. Similarly, if you can open developer console and see at which point the `undefined` exception is being thrown to help narrow down where the issue is. Regardless.. the above issues still should be looked at :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your for loop has finished looping when your ajax results come in (and your success handler fires). This means that in your success handler, where you have `words[i]`, the value of `i` is equal to words.length (if you don't believe me, try logging or alerting `i` from within your handler); and `words[words.length]` will always be `undefined`. What you need to do is to wrap your ajax call in an immediately invoked function and within this new function's scope, capture the value of `words[i]`:

```
(function () {

    var nextword = words[i];
    /* do ajax call and use 'nextword' instead of 'words[i]' */      

}());
```